# "In ihrer Straße"-the use of case

Tags: verb, wechselpraeposition

Here is a sentence:

> Was würden bloß die Nachbarn sagen, sollten die Potters eines Tages in ihrer Straße aufkreuzen?

My question is why is the "in" associated with the Dative case rather than Accusative? Doesn't the context imply a change of location here?

Answer (score 4):

As a very rough rule of thumb (that I feel sometimes fits a lot better than the "change of location" rule which can be a bit awkward): If you can use "into" in English, you should use "in" + accusative in German. If not, use dative.

*Aufkreuzen*'s meaning turns out to be "to show up, appear, turn up". And just like you can't use "into" with these verbs in English, you can't use accusative in German.

If you want to be picky and continue to use your "change of location" rule: In order to be able to *turn up* somewhere, you must have been there already (just not appeared yet), so very likely there is no change of location involved. But that sounds like nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

The verb is essential here; one could indicate the movement (and use the accusative you expect) by writing

> .. wenn die Potters eines Tages in ihre Straße **kämen**.

For *aufkreuzen* and *erscheinen* just a location is given. Compare this to:

> Der Mond erscheint am Himmel.

Surely there is movement involved, but the sentence just makes a statement concerning the **location**.

So while movement has to be considered the verb and its context are more important.